# How do you divide pandas columns by a scalar?

Tags: pandas

I have a file from excel in a pandas dataframe. I have many columns and rows and I want to divide all column and row values (except NaN) by a scalar(2.45). This is what i have:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Ozflux.dailyLE.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1', skiprows=0, index_col=2, na_values=[-9999])
ET = df.iloc[4: , 3: ]/2.45
print (ET)
```

It doesn't give me an error but the values are not divided in ET. Anyone has solution?

Comment: Can you share df.head(7) and df.info(), as your code should work it might come from what's in the dataframe

Answer (score 18):

If the whole DataFrame is numerical you can divide all the values (even the NaN's) by 2.45 at once

```
df= df/2.45
print(df)
```

Notice I had to replace the DataFrame with `df =` to make it stick.

Comment: I have a column in a pandas dataframe, running it in Jupyter notebook, and I tried this but not working.  Here's what I tried: df['a] = df['a]/10.  Each time I try it the kernel dies.  I also tried creating a new column, so df['a1'] = df['a']/10 but it seems to take forever and nothing happens.  Column is only 40,000 long. @Back2Basics

Comment: First one fails because of a missing quote.  You may have data of the wrong type in there?  try checking >> df['a'].dtype   if it's of type "O" (a python object which is not numerical), you can try changing it with df['a']= pd.to_numeric(df['a']) or hunt down the bad data.

Comment: Is the other way around if `df = 2.45 / df` efficient or is there a better way?

Comment: Think about what happens if that’s a zero or a NAN value.  My answer is still “that’s the most efficient way to do that operation “. But it really depends on your data.

Answer (score 3):

first, it is better to make a copy of your original data frame.
Then you can divide any column by scalar as follows. Assume there is a column named ET

```
new_dataframe=df[:]
new_dataframe['ET']=new_dataframe['ET]'/2.45
```